# Sencha touch Create Apk

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I had done an app using sencha touch 2 that has web service implemented and now we need to make its APK and test it on Android phone, I had searched many places still cant find an easy way to do it. Is it more complex than what we done to create the app? please give me a right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of documentation on the internet about this. Anyway, this is what is you have to do if you want to create a APK file for your sencha application.

You need to use phonegap to create a native package with sencha touch libraries. This a multiple step process. Take a look at this blog http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/20/SenchaPhoneGap/

Answer (score 0):

1: Make sure you have android sdk, adb, ant, nodejs and ruby installed and working on your system, install cordova with npm and compass with gems

2: init cordova `sencha cordova init com.mycompany.MyApp MyApp`, declare android platform in app.json file `"platforms":"android"` inside cordova section

3: Build native package `sencha app build native`

4: Locate debug APK path and install it into device `adb -d install  -r cordova/platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-debug.apk` (make sure usb debugging is enabled)

5: Run APK on the device: `adb shell am start -n com.mycompany.MyApp/com.mycompany.MyApp.CordovaApp`